# Laravel 5.5 Naming Route::resource for later use

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing, laravel-5.5, laravel-artisan

How can I name my `Route::resource` so I can call it later in Laravel 5.5?

This works
`Route::get('newclientTAB', 'NewClientControllerTAB@index')->name('newclientTAB');`

This doesn't
`Route::resource('articles','ArticleController')->name('articles');`

Answer (score 6):

If you use:

```
Route::resource('articles','ArticleController')
```

Laravel will automatically set names for you routes.

You can run:

```
php artisan route:list
```

to see them.

The will have names:

- articles.index
- articles.store
- articles.create
- articles.show
- articles.update
- articles.destroy
- articles.edit

However if you want to use custom name prefix you can set it like this:

```
Route::resource('articles','ArticleController', ['names' => 'xyz'])
```

and then your routes will have names `xyz.index`, `xyz.store` and so on

If you want to go further you can also set individual names for example:

```
Route::resource('articles','ArticleController', ['names' => ['create' => 'foo','update' => 'bar']])
```

so you can set names only for some routes so you will get `foo`, `bar` and `articles.index`, `articles.show` and so on

Comment: Little later, but this should work `Route::resource('articles','ArticleController')->names('xyz');` Notice change of method from `name` to `names`! Works in Laravel 5.6 (not tested in earlier versions)